# Lazarus (Delphi/FPC): constructor in class helper is not executed

Tags: delphi, treeview, lazarus, freepascal

I'm trying to find a universal** solution to extend the built-in Treeview/TreeNode by some features such as ToolTips per Node. So first I derived a `TExtendedTreeNode = class(TTreeNode)` and added a corresponding property which seems to work fine - I can add TExtendedTreeNodes with different ToolTips for each node.

For the next step, I want to use the TTreeView.OnMouseMove event to show the corresponding ToolTip, but what is the best solution to extend this functionality in a universal** way?

My idea was to use a `class helper for TTreeView`:

```
type
  TTreeViewExtension = class helper for TTreeView
  private
    procedure ShowNodeToolTips(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
  public
    constructor Create(AnOwner: TComponent);
  end;
```

...

```
constructor TTreeViewExtension.Create(AnOwner: TComponent);

begin
  inherited Create(AnOwner);

  ShowMessage('TTreeViewExtension.Create');

  self.OnMouseMove := @self.ShowNodeToolTips;
end;
```

The code is compiled without warnings or errors, but this constructor is NOT executed on creation of a treeview in my form.

And yes, I'm using `advancedrecords` in `objfpc mode` in both, my form unit and my extension unit - in order to use the class helper:

```
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}
{$modeswitch advancedrecords+}
```

** "universal" means, I want to use the integrated controls from my Lazarus IDE at least for the TreeView control, but use the extended functionality without writing code twice.

Comment: Create the descendant of the TTreeView instead and override its protected method `procedure MouseMove(Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer); override;`

Comment: Yup, don't abuse baroque constructs like class helpers if it can be done in a forward way. I'm not sure that class helpers allow to override methods anyway. Class helpers are a crutch, not an swiss army nice.

Comment: @Marco: I don't know about FPC, but in Delphi, class helpers can't override virtual or dynamic methods, for obvious reasons. And indeed, they are a crutch, originally intended to make TObject and some other classes compatible with corresponding C# classes. They are used for more now, but they remain a crutch.

Comment: Right, seems to be exactly the same in FPC.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use the already available `OnHint` event to show these tooltips. The `TTreeView.OnHint` event already returns you reference to the tree node that is beneath the mouse cursor so you should not have any problem reading your custom hints (tooltips) from the node.

If the tips can be shown in a single line of text you can simply change the value of `Hint` variable that is exposed in this event method.

You can easily read such value from your `Extended TreeNode` by typecasting the `Node` constant returned by the event method to your `TExtendedTreeNode` class.
Don't forget to check if the node in question is indeed of the right class.

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1Hint(Sender: TObject; const Node: TTreeNode;
  var Hint: string);
begin
  //Check to see if the node beneath the cursor is the extended node
  if Node is TExtendedTreeNode then
    //if it is change the hint text to the custom hint stored in the
    //node itself
    Hint := TExtendedTreeNode(Node).CustomHint
  //Else change the hint to empty string so no hintbox will be shown
  else Hint := '';
end;
```

And if you don't want any hint text to be shown and show your information in a different way you simply set the `Hint` value to an empty string.

```
procedure TForm1.TreeView1Hint(Sender: TObject; const Node: TTreeNode;
  var Hint: string);
begin
  //Set Hint to empty string in order to not show any hint box
  Hint := '';
  //Do some other code instead if you like
  MessageBeep(0);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this doesn't solve my main question of integrating it into all existing and future TreeViews created by the IDE's form designer in my application without writing additional code.
Ok, maybe I didn't explain it unmistakable - my English is not the very best one.

Comment: In that case I think that the best solution would be to also extend TTreeView component with additional code and replace all your existing TTreeView components with the extended one.

Comment: Looks like Lazarus has no TTreeview.OnHint event - I guess it was created in newer versions of Delphi and Lazarus will support it in a later release... There's only a TTreeview..OnShowHint event - this is better than MouseMove because it's only called when a new hint is required, but I have to determine the current node in the same way as above.
I'm just getting into development of an IDE component which can be registered as a visual control in the form designer. Now I know it's at least possible and this is indeed the best solution.